# XMLHttpRequest timeout case - onreadystatechange executes before ontimeout?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am using XMLHttpRequest to make asynchronous GET requests. I have

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {//Handle only if the state has completed
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            successHandler.call(context, xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            console.warn('onreadystatechange:' + new Date().getTime());
            failureHandler.call(context, xhr.status, xhr.statusText);
        }
    }
};
xhr.ontimeout = function () {
    console.warn('ontimeout: ' + new Date().getTime());
    failureHandler.call(context, 0, 'timeout');
};
```

I am forcing timeout using network throttling. I observe both `onreadystatechange` and `ontimeout` callbacks are called in case of timeouts, `onreadystatechange` preceding `ontimeout`.  I was under the impression that only one of the two will be executed. I am using Chrome. Does anybody know if this is expected?

Comment: Why were you under the impression they were exclusive events? I know nothing about `ontimeout`, but if the `readyState` **changes** (whether it be because of a timeout, completion, or error), I would expect the `onreadystatechange` method to be called. The `XMLHttpRequest` keeps track of its `readyState`, and timing out should definitely change it

Comment: The readyState changes to the value 4 which is a `DONE` state. How do we know if the ajax has indeed failed, because even the `statusText` is blank?

Comment: @neer I believe you could rely on xhr.status = 0 if timeout occurs before the code is received from the server: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern solution is to use appropriate XMLHttpRequest events: onload and onerror if you want to handle these cases separately, onloadend if you wish to detect HTTP request completion regardless of success, and ontimeout for timeouts. When a timeout occurs, ontimeout is called, but not onloadend. onreadystatechange looks like it's best left to die quietly. The full set of events can be found here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#events

Since the onreadystatechange→ontimeout sequence doesn't appear to afflict IE 8, for my purposes I'm happy to do the following: use onreadystatechange in IE 8, and onloadend in Firefox/modern MSIE (using the following test to see if the event is defined: if ("onloadend" in httpObj) ...).

This is an internal system, so this suffices for me; for the OP, more testing may be required.

Answer (score 0):

**onreadystatechange** is called before **ontimeout**, to work around this I used **setTimeout** and something that indicates that **ontimeout** was called, i decided like this:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (){
    if (xhr.status == 0){
        return setTimeout(()=>{
           if (xhr['istimeout']) return

           onResponse({status:xhr.status, statusText:xhr.statusText})
        }, 1)
    }
}

xhr.ontimeout = function handleTimeout() {
     xhr['istimeout'] = true
     onResponse({
         status: xhr.status,
         statusText: `timeout of xxxms exceeded`,
     })
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.